# concrete patio, grading, geotextile

Tags: concrete, patio, slab, gravel, grading

I am about to make a concrete slab patio along the wall of my house facing the backyard (38' long house wall, 10' wide concrete slab).

To ensure proper water drainage (now, water may stay next to the foundation). Also, it should hold the table/chairs/mangal and people (no vehicles). The soil is all clay here; It's South TX, so there are no frosts.

- I assume it should be graded with ~2" slope, is it optimal?.
- The contractor says putting the slab on clay, but I suppose some 2" of gravel is needed, right?
- Will 4.5" with rebars work for the slab?
- Then, should I put some woven geotextile under the gravel?
- And is a black expansion joint material enough just between the slab and house foundation, or do I need to make this patio of several slabs with expansion joints in between?
- I should not connect it to the house foundation (which has a warranty), so I guess it may shift with the clay.

Comment: Why is the clay shifting? You said there was no frost.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. If you can't do that, your post includes too many questions or is to broad. (It is.)

Comment: the clay is shifting because of dry/rain cycles.

Answer (score 1):

2 percent slope = 1/4" per foot so 2" is about right over 10'.

Your house should have perimeter drains so I don't think the gravel is needed.

4.5" with rebar is fine.

If you are putting a gravel drain layer under your slab, I'd put down at least landscape fabric to keep the gravel clean, I'd also put poly over the gravel before pouring the concrete.

Is it highly expansive clay that expands with the wet season?

Concrete wants to shrink with drying and the general rule is you want the same dimension each way so a 10'x10' is fine but a 10'x38' is going to shrink more one way than the other and it will want to crack.  This comes down to mix, weather and luck.  You can saw cut it after pouring for a thinner isolation joint.  You can also  put separators under the concrete that come almost up to the surface that will cause the concrete to crack at those areas in a semi-controller fashion.

In Texas, outside, I'd opt for saw cutting (only need to go 1/2" deep) and break it into four ~10'x10' pieces.

Comment: thank you Fresh Codemonger. You mean making "control joints", right?  Which are "partial cuts". So, it will be enough?

Comment: thank you @fresh-codemonger. 
I don't see perimeter drains, so one of the functions of this patio is to ensure water drains away from the foundation. My concern - does not it lead to too dry and shrinking clay next to the foundation that may harm it?  This clay is somewhat expansive, but I am not sure about the degree - I am not experienced.

The poly between gravel and concrete - that means the gravel should be between 2 layers of plastic? (geotextile below and poly above).  Does not it lead to problems if water gets into the gravel - it will accumulate in that layer?

Comment: Not exactly.  2 *degrees* is about 3.5% slope.  1/4" per ft is about 2 *percent*.  Roads are usually graded with a 2% crown.

Comment: yeah partial cuts, control joints or crack isolation..    encourages the cracks to form there as opposed to elsewhere.  You don't want any drains below the footing, you can have them next to the footing.  geotextile allows water through it, the poly won't.